# Rails instance variable not updating in a thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I am working on a basic chat setup using websockets, redis, and threads.  I'm creating an array of clients before the thread starts and then updating the clients array.  However, the array of clients is never updated in the thread.  So, when I try to publish to the connected clients, nothing is published.  I'm working off an [example directly on Heroku](https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo) and can't figure out why the clients array is not updating.

Here is my code:

```
class ChatBackend
  KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 # in seconds
  CHANNEL        = "chat-demo"


  def initialize(app)
    @app     = app
    @clients = []

    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
    @redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
    Thread.new do

      redis_sub = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
      redis_sub.subscribe(CHANNEL) do |on|
        on.message do |channel, msg|
            # @clients never gets updated, always stays empty
          @clients.each {|ws| ws.send(msg) }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
      ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: KEEPALIVE_TIME })
      ws.on :open do |event|
        @clients << ws
      end

      ws.on :message do |event|        
        @redis.publish(CHANNEL, prepare(event.data))
      end

      ws.on :close do |event|
        @clients.delete(ws)
        ws = nil
      end

      # Return async Rack response
      ws.rack_response

    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  private
  def prepare(data)
    json = JSON.parse(message)
    json.each {|key, value| json[key] = ERB::Util.html_escape(value) }
    JSON.generate(json)    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me all day to pin down, but it's covered in the wiki issues of the Heroku example [here](https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo/issues/1):

> Specifying workers puts puma in clustered mode, and broke my slightly
>   modified version of the middleware presented in this example.
>
> I verified that the messages are being published properly to the redis
>   pubsub channel, and that the redis subscription inside of the thread
>   does receive the messages and fires the on.message block, but the ws
>   client in the browser never gets the message.
>
> This is due to @clients being an empty array inside the thread (for a
>   reason that is escaping me), meaning that the block passed to
>   @clients.each is never executed, so the message dies there.
>
> Accessing @clients outside of that thread does return all of the open
>   ws connections properly.
>
> Removing the workers 3 line fixes the issue, but I figured I would
>   report it, in case someone else runs into this themselves.